# Prove without using truth table that $[(p↔q)∧(q↔r)∧(r↔p)] ≡ [(p→q)∧(q→r)∧(r→p)]$

Tags: logic

> Prove without using truth table that $[(p↔q)∧(q↔r)∧(r↔p)] ≡ [(p→q)∧(q→r)∧(r→p)]$

I tried to prove this by rewriting the first part using $∧$, $∨$ and the fact that $(p↔q)≡(p→q)∧(q→p)$ to conclude the second part, but it seemed a long way to adopt:
$$
[(p↔q)∧(q↔r)∧(r↔p)]\\
≡ [(p→q)∧(q→p)∧(q→r)∧(r→q)∧(r→p)∧(p→r)]\\
≡ [(¬p∨q)∧(¬q∨p)∧(¬q∨r)∧(¬r∨q)∧(¬r∨p)∧(¬p∨r)]\\
≡ \ ...
$$
Do you have any idea how I can prove this in an easier way? Thanks.

Comment: What methods are allowed?  For example, would you be allowed to present a formal proof (for example using some natural deduction system) of the equivalence?  (Which would be the way I'd tend to approach it.)  Or are you restricted to only being allowed to use direct algebraic manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is immediate that the LHS implies the RHS.  For converse: start by assuming RHS true.

Immediate that $p\to q$.  Also $q \to r$ which implies $p$.
Therefore $(p \to q) \land (q\to p)$  $\therefore p \iff q$.

Rest of converse is very similar.

Comment: (+1)Logical question handled with logic..

Answer (score 1):

$LHS\leq RHS$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
LHS &= \bigwedge\big\{(p\to q)\land (q\to p),(q\to r)\land(r\to q),(r\to p)\land(p\to r)\big\}\\
&=\bigwedge\big\{p\to q,q\to p,q\to r,r\to q,r\to p,p\to r\big\}\\
&\leq \bigwedge\big\{p\to q,q\to r,r\to p\big\}\\
&=RHS
\end{aligned}
$$

$LHS\geq RHS$: Take the meet of
\begin{align*}
(p\to r)&\geq (p\to q)\land(q\to r)\\
(q\to p)&\geq (q\to r)\land(r\to p)\\
(r\to q)&\geq (r\to p)\land(p\to q)\\
(p\to q)&=(p\to q)\\
(q\to r)&=(q\to r)\\
(r\to p)&=(r\to p)
\end{align*}
and you have
$$
\bigwedge\big\{p\to q,q\to p,q\to r,r\to q,r\to p,p\to r\big\}\geq
\bigwedge\big\{p\to q,q\to r,r\to p\}
$$
i.e.,
$$
\bigwedge\big\{(p\to q)\land (q\to p),(q\to r)\land(r\to q),(r\to p)\land(p\to r)\big\}\geq \bigwedge\big\{p\to q,q\to r,r\to p\}
$$
as desired.

So the two sides are equal in the Lindenbaum algebra.

Answer (score 1):

[Sorting boolean values so that false is less than true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet#Partial_order_approach), the left-hand side says $p=q=r=p$, while the right-hand side says $p\le q\le r\le p$.